# KVM Centos 7 - unable to login to virsh console

Tags: centos, kvm

I have installed KVM server and all works fine. while I reading the book I need to connect virtual machine through the console. I mean, with virsh console machine.

but when I do it, the virsh hangs on Escape character is ^]

```
Connected to domain <vm name>
Escape character is ^]
```

Comment: But you did connect successfully!

Answer (score 1):

Use `virt-manager` to view your machine if using KVM.

1. install xming on your local System/Desktop.
2. Enable **X11 forwarding yes** on your ssh configuration file of KVM server. Reload sshd service.
3. Open putty--> enable x11 --> enter KVM server ip--> Login with user.
4. In terminal use **virt-manager &** to open a graphical console of Vm's.
5. After You would need to define a tty to be used as a virtual console. In case you have access to your vm either using vnc or ssh create the following file

   ```
   vi /etc/init/ttyS0.conf**
   ```
6. The content should be something like

   ```
   start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]
   stop on runlevel [!2345]

   respawn
   exec /sbin/getty -L 38400 ttyS0 vt102  # This is your term type vt102
   ```
7. Save these settings and subsequently from your host machine

   ```
   virsh shutdown {domain-id, domain-name or domain-uuid}; service libvirtd stop; service libvirtd start; virsh start {domain-id, domain-name or domain-uuid}
   ```
8. `virsh console {domain-id, domain-name or domain-uuid}`